# How to deploy meteor app in production server using Centos7

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

How to deploy the meteor in centos7.We installed the meteor and meteorjs packages and nodejs.
But we unable to open the production link.Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First of all, you don't need to install meteor on production server. Node.js is enough.
- On my Centos server, I use nginx + supervisord to run my meteor app.
- You should build your app with "meteor build --directory " command. With this command you will get a bundle directory. Compress that bundle folder and upload it to the server. Example

  ```
  meteor build --directory <some_path>
  ```
- Extract in on the server, then

  ```
  cd bundle/programs/server
  npm install
  ```
- Example meteor app config in supervisord.conf file. All the meteor app specific config is in the 'environment' variable on this configuration. There will be other entries in your supervisord.conf file. You will have to add this one for your meteor app. For more info on supervisord, visit http://supervisord.org

  ```
  [program:my-meteor-app]
  command=node main.js              ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
  directory=/home/path_where_bundle_is/bundle
  process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
  numprocs=1                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
  autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
  autorestart=unexpected        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
  user=app_user                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
  redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
  stdout_logfile=/var/log/meteor.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
  stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
  stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
  ;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
  ;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
  stderr_logfile=/var/log/meteor_err.log        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
  stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
  stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
  ;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
  ;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
  environment=PORT="3003", ROOT_URL="https://your_url",MAIL_URL="smtp://xxx:xxx@smtp.mailgun.org:25",MONGO_URL="mongodb://xxx:xxx@localhost/databasename"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
  ;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)
  ```
- For nginx configuration, this is my configuration concerning meteor app (this is not the whole config file just the part necessary for meteor):

  ```
      location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3003/;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }
  ```

For more detailed information on setting up nginx, you can check out digitalocean documentation:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx

When everything is ok:

```
    supervisorctl start all
    service nginx start
```

- I am running meteor app on port 3003 and redirecting requests to that port using nginx. You might want to add an iptables rule to drop connections to port 3003, so that only nginx can connect to port 3003. Here are two iptables rules to deny mongodb and port 3003 connections from public networks.

  ```
  iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 27017 -j DROP
  iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3003 -j DROP
  ```

Comment: I followed your answer and it works thanks. But now, I would like to run my meteor app on another location, /app for example. But when I change `location /app {...}` it show to me 404 page of my app. An idea? Thanks